# Header change doesn't trigger rebuild .o (using .d dependency file)

Tags: makefile

I have a such simple makefile:

```
#Compiler flags
CC := gcc
INCLDIR := -I./includes

#Directories and files
BUILDDIR := build
STLIB := $(BUILDDIR)/libbinary_tree.a

DEPS:=$(BUILDDIR)/binary_tree.d

-include $(DEPS)

$(BUILDDIR)/binary_tree.o: ./source_files/binary_tree.c
    mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CC) -c $< $(INCLDIR) -o $@
    $(CC) -MM $(INCLDIR) ./source_files/binary_tree.c > $(BUILDDIR)/binary_tree.d

.PHONY: build clean

build: $(BUILDDIR)/binary_tree.o
    ar -rcs $(STLIB) $(BUILDDIR)/binary_tree.o

clean:
    rm -r $(BUILDDIR)
```

First calling `make build` creates `./build/binary_tree.d` file, that contains `binary_tree.o: source_files/binary_tree.c includes/binary_tree.h`, but if I change header `includes/binary_tree.h` and then call `make build` - it doesn't rebuild `build/binary_tree.o`, only create library /libbinary_tree.a. I have no clue, why makefile ignores changes in the header file. Could you tell me where my logic is wrong, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because, `binary_tree.o` is not the same file as `build/binary_tree.o`.

So your definition of the prerequisite relationship:

```
binary_tree.o: source_files/binary_tree.c includes/binary_tree.h
```

is referring to a totally different file than the target of your compilation rule:

```
$(BUILDDIR)/binary_tree.o: ./source_files/binary_tree.c
```

Comment: So, I should add the .o files' path in the .d files. Thanks again, MadScientist!